# Can disconnecting be used as a legit strategy in Dota 2 to aid your team?

Tags: dota-2

To give more xp and gold to the remaining players, are there any cases of **a player disconnecting as a deliberate strategy**? That is, a strategy that is planned beforehand, not a rage quit or fulfilling a pub request to "uninstall dota". And if so, is it allowed in tournament play?

Having played a game on a team with 3 disconnects (perhaps rage quits over stealing farm or something equally trivial, in any case I didn't see it), and then the two of us that were remaining could quickly buy strong items and won the game against the five remaining opponents. This was a low skill match, but I imagine similar could happen in higher skill arenas.

Note that it would still be possible for the remaining players to control the abandoned hero, so they're not completely out of the game, and they could even continue, for example, farming for more gold for the team. It would require someone with the skill to control both their own hero and the abandoned one, but controlling multiple heroes is not uncommon in Dota2 (e.g. Lone Druid or Meepo). The redistributed gold could be enough to give the team a significant edge, buying some more expensive items sooner.

Comment: No. The marginal benefit of a disconnect (being increased experience and potential resources for each of the other players) is vastly outweighed by the lack of map pressure and fight potential, particularly in organised play.

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvotes (I've upped, as I've pondered the same question a while ago). Either someone misread and thought you we're looking for help to "cheat" in this fashion yourself, or maybe it was because your question was rather short, without any (shared) research or more in-depth explanation of how this strategy would work.

Comment: Fair enough. An example of this strategy might be if one player spent a large amount of time jungling, bought minimal items, and then disconnected to share their gold with the other players, giving them strong items sooner. They may then either stay disconnected (to give other players an xp boost), or reconnect after 5 minutes (once they have "abandoned" and their gold distributed).

Comment: Are you very sure gold from disconnected players goes to teammates? I haven't paid attention but thought this was not the case.

Comment: Pretty sure. Several forum posts say similar things: "The gold of the disconnected player is split to the teammates." and "After abandonment, any gold acquired by the abandoned hero will be evenly distributed between teammates." This is why items on abandon heroes are usually sold: the gold goes to the other players.

I'm not really sure what happens with XP, only that I seemed to level up much faster when there were only 2 players on our team. Perhaps it was just because there weren't others around to split XP of kills with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on experience and gut feeling: **no, this is not a viable strategy**, except perhaps in *extremely* unique situations. In pro play the effects of a player leaving will always be negative.

In lower level play there may be a few other things to consider why it'd be beneficial to have teammates leave:

- The player was feeding, leading enemies towards fellow teammates, or in other similar ways making the opponents stronger;
- The player may've been drawing teammates into useless chat (flame wars, etc), where they'd otherwise be doing something beneficial;

The latter actually happens a lot in low(ish) level play, I see it a lot at 3K MMR. Sometimes a player leaving brings a sort of calm to your team allowing you to focus and win after all. This is especially true if leftover players can still fill all essential roles for endgame play (control, carry).

Finally, about your last question: "Is it allowed in tournament play?". I'm no expert on official rules, but I imagine most rule sets are similar to [this one from joindota](http://www.joindota.com/en/statics/rules_pro), with these relevant sections (emphasis mine):

> 5.3 Disconnects & Reconnects
>
> If a player disconnects, the game is to be paused instantly. Everyone has up to ten minutes to reconnect to the game (if the same person disconnects more than once, all times get added up). If this time is passed, the opposing team may continue the game, unless an admin demands the opposite. The affected player is in this case still allowed to rejoin later on.

and

> 5.7 Ending
>
> A game is finished, when an Ancient Fortress is destroyed, when one team obviously forfeits, **when the majority of a team leaves on purpose**, or when the administration decides on it.

These rules don't really "forbid" leaving as a strategy, but from the tone you can kind of guess that it's not even remotely considered as a viable strategy.

Basically your question is similar to:

> Are soccer players allowed to score an own goal to throw off their opponents mentally?

I guess it's "allowed", but the rules won't say much about this situation as there's no real way anyone'd consider it a viable strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Lies all, I have been in 3 separate games where one player is highly skilled so when other players abandon (on purpose), the smurf pro player gets so much money that it becomes impossible for a team of five to make the ramp up if they cannot get kills.

This is an exploit that does exist.  Abandons in any match by any player should automatically not be counted..