# Does gold for disconnected players in any way flow to team mates?

Tags: dota-2

In [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/198249/11084) it is claimed that gold for disconnected players will flow to team mates in several different ways:

> it would still be possible [after disconnects for] remaining players to control the abandoned hero, [who] could even continue, for example, farming for more gold for the team

And in comments:

> @Jeroen wrote: Are you very sure gold from disconnected players goes to teammates?
>
> @Qubei wrote: Several forum posts say similar things: "The gold of the disconnected player is split to the teammates." and "After abandonment, any gold acquired by the abandoned hero will be evenly distributed between teammates." This is why items on abandon heroes are usually sold: the gold goes to the other players.

Is this true? In what ways (if any) does gold flow from disconnected players to remaining teammates?

In spirit of Stack Overflow I'd share my research, but [searching Arqade comes up empty (apart from linked question)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdota-2%5D+gold+disconnect), and short of ruining a pub, empiricism is out of the question. So: does anyone know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, if you are just *disconnected***, your gold will still increase and won't be splitted and shared with your team mates. In the same fashion, while you are disconnected, they won't be able to drop or sell your items.

**However, the moment you *abandon* a game** (either by not reconnecting for 5 min or by voluntary leaving) all your gold gets divided amongst remaining team mates equally, and your items can be sold. The gold from the sell is also divided and shared. From that point on you still get gold over time, but any time the amount can be divided by the number of remaining team mates (if 4 players remain, every 4 gold acquired; if 3 remain, every 3 gold acquired; etc.) it will be divided and each member of your team gets 1 extra gold.

Comment: Its not true, I reconnected before abandon but all my gold was gone somehow.

Comment: The answer is correct for the first disconnecting player. But every player abandoning the game after the first one, would still keep his gold because they would no longer be abandoning the game (since it was already abandoned). (disclaimer: maybe valve fixed this by now, but i doubt it) Also there are a few glitches that will keep the player from abandoning the game, in which case even after 5 minutes the gold will not be shared.